What's the first badass standing against the moon scene in anime?
Many anime use this type of scene to give off a badass vibe. This works quite good. I wonder who is the first to come up with this idea. Which is the first anime to use this type of scene?

Added Content After Edition:
Gotta edit to state more clearly since people seem to miss the point. What I was asking is the scene used to build up the typical (MC/villain) badass vibe. This kind of scene is at night where the surroundings is dark, with the full moon being the sole source of light while the character is barely illuminated. It's supposed to hype up the audience and make them say, 'oh, that's sick', after watching the scene. Just as you can feel in the pic I gave earlier, these scenes, especially the Zenitsu and Night Raid ones, serves to manifest the powerfulness of the characters. (The Luffy one is a parody though.)
Yet another similar example (not standing tho) is when Akame showed up at night to duel with Zank. She jumped high up into the sky and was silhouetted by the red full moon. 

I believe this trope was first used on a Live-Action movie, "E.T. the Extraterrestrial" (1982), if I'm not mistaken. Because the iconic shot became the logo of Steven Spielberg's production company Amblin Entertainment. The trope is called "Full Moon Silhouette".

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FullMoonSilhouette

As far as anime goes, I'd say that Sailor Moon is the most iconic. But not until later seasons. In the beginning they preferred to use a half moon.
1992, Bishoujo Senshi Sailor Moon

1993, Bishoujo Senshi Sailor Moon R


1994, Bishoujo Senshi Sailor Moon S


1995, Bishoujo Senshi Sailor Moon Super S

Then there's..
2000, Zelda no Densetsu: Mujura no Kamen


Sorry, but the Sailor Moon thing is not what I asked tho. I edited the question to make it more clear what I was asking.

That's what popularized the moon in the background, though. And I fail to see how it's any different from your examples. In Sailor Moon it also hypes up the audience and makes her look like a badass. Same with the Zelda picture.

Reposting what Henkyo commented so that it can be seen as an answer:

I believe this trope was first used on a Live-Action movie, "E.T. the Extraterrestrial" (1982), if I'm not mistaken. Because the iconic shot became the logo of Steven Spielberg's production company Amblin Entertainment. The trope is called 'Full Moon Silhouette'.

This would make sense as I'm sure many people writing manga are from a generation that would have watched E.T. All it takes is one person to use it and then it gets repeated over and over. Not sure what the first anime to do it is though.

OP said "in anime." E.T. is not an anime.

It's more likely to be inspired by classical Japanese art than such a movie. What specifically is unclear, but there are ukiyo-e block print art depicting silhouette against the moon from as early as the Edo period. Baisotei Gengyo being a notable artist for the work, Crows in Moonlight as well as those from after that period
